# Devise destroy user create bug in index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, destroy

I got a problem with my website in local when I delete an User with Devise on rails. The user is correctly deleted but now, when I go on the event index page, with normally a list of all the event, I got this message :

> undefined method `pseudo' for nil:NilClass

It's because the deleted user has created event before being destroy, but now the application couldn't find the creator of the event etc...

I don't know how to fix it : 
 - How can I do if I want to keep the content he had created?
 - should I delete all the content that the user delete in the same time?

I don't know if my problem is clear but I hope someone can help, thanks!

Comment: You need to provide more context of the relation; does the user has some content. how is it related. What is the code in the index page ? If you are referencing to the user somewhere else after it is deleted, you will get errrors.

Comment: Yes sorry, i can resolve the problem with  >> has_many :articles, foreign_key: 'author_id', class_name: "Article", dependent: :destroy
In fact this was cause because I got some "class_name" I don't take in consideration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails gives you two options, from their guide:

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one

```
has_one :credit_card, dependent: :destroy  # destroys the associated credit card
has_one :credit_card, dependent: :nullify  # updates the associated records foreign key value to NULL rather than destroying it
```

As you can see from the comments, the first option, `dependent: :destroy`, will delete any associated content when the user is destroyed. `dependent: :nullify` will set the user_id for the content to null

In your case, it appears a user has_many contents? Or has_one :content, either way the dependent: :destroy bit would be the same. To destroy the content when a user is destroyed:

```
has_one :content, dependent: :destroy
```

or

```
has_many :contents, dependent: :destroy
```

And to keep the content but set its owner to nil:

```
has_one :content, dependent: :mullify
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I still had some problem with only dependent: :destroy, I can resolve it with foreign_key >> has_many :articles, foreign_key: 'author_id', class_name: "Article", dependent: :destroy